# How to populate existing records with new data?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a domain entity of analyzer which contains some properties and I've added a new property `CommitsAnalyzerSettings` to it:

```
public class RepositoryAnalyzer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Repository analyzer Id.
    /// </summary>
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Commits analyzer settings.
    /// </summary>
    public CommitsAnalyzerSettings? CommitsAnalyzerSettings { get; set; }
}
```

Now when I create a new instance of analyzer it automatically creates an instance of settings - everything is fine. But how can I create `CommitsAnalyzerSettings` for analyzers that were created earlier?

Comment: It's just a property, like any other. You create an object of the appropriate type and you assign that object to the property. What's the actual problem?

Comment: @jmcilhinney I mean, there're analyzers that were created earlier and now they don't have a settings, I need somehow create new records of settings and assign them to these older analyzers

Comment: The answer is still the same. If you have records in two tables that are not related and now need to be, you get both records as entities and assign one of them to the property of the other. Again, what's the actual problem? There's no magic here. Either you have an existing object or you need to create a new one, then set the property. How exactly you structure your application to do that is up to you. It could be done any number of specific ways and we don't know anything about your app to even provide vague advice, which is not what this site is for anyway.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your question is that you have one Entity in EF Core and you are adding one more Navigation property to this Entity and now you want data of this Navigation property for existing records. If that is correct then my simple solution is to add some default data in the Navigation property table for the existing parent Entity.

Here, in your case, you have to add data in the `CommitsAnalyzerSettings` table with the parent id of the `RepositoryAnalyzer` table. So it will automatically populate the data in the CommitsAnalyzerSettings property.